# How do I prove $S(n,3)= \frac16 \cdot (3^n - 3\cdot2^n + 3)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ denote Stirling's number of 2nd kind,

then how do I prove $S(n,3)= \frac16 \cdot (3^n - 3\cdot2^n + 3)$

I know the recurrence relation for $S$

$S(n,k) = S(n-1,k-1) + k\cdot S(n-1,k)$

Also $S(n,2)= 2^{n-1} - 1$

$S(n,n-1)= C(n,2)$

Answer (score 3):

$S(n,3)$ is the number of ways to partition $n$ elements into $3$ unlabeled non-empty subsets. Thus $3!S(n,3)=6S(n,3)$ is the number of ways to partition $n$ elements into $3$ labeled non-empty subsets. We can partition $n$ elements into $3$ labeled subsets in $3^n$ ways. For each of the $3$ labeled subsets, this includes $2^n$ partitions in which that subset is empty, so we need to subtract $3\cdot2^n$. But then we're subtracting each of the $3$ partitions where two labeled subsets are empty twice instead of once, so we have to add $3$ back.

Answer (score 1):

The relation $S(n,3) = S(n-1,2) + 3 S(n-1,3)$ enables you to give an inductive proof.

Suppose $S(k,3)= \frac16 (3^k - 3\times2^k + 3)$, then $$S(k+1,3) = S(k,2) + 3 S(k,3)=2^{k-1}-1+ \frac36 (3^k - 3\times2^k + 3)$$
$$S(k+1,3) = \frac16\left (6\times2^{k-1}-6+ 3^{k+1} - 9\times2^k + 9\right)=\frac16\left (3^{k+1}- 3\times2^{k+1} + 3\right)$$
The formula is true for $S(3,3)=1$ and is therefore true for all $S(n,3), n\ge 3$.